# Pass values to twig file from #theme options

Tags: 8, theming

I need to create a select field in a config form and pass values to it along with custom #theme options.
Its easy to pass header & row values. But after selecting a value from select box, I need to load another dropdown, Below is my reference code:

addslider.php

```
 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 $vid = 'my_categories';
 $terms =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vid);

 foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $custom_categories[$term->tid] = str_repeat('-', $term->depth) . $term->name;
 }
  $form['block']['sliders'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => $this->t('My Sliders'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#theme'  => 'my_custom_slider_table',
);

foreach ($block['sliders'] as $key => $slider) {

$form['block']['sliders'][$key]['tid'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'select',
  '#title'         => t('Categories'),
  '#options'       => $custom_categories,
  '#required'      => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => !empty($slider['tid']) ? $slider['tid'] : NULL,
);
}
```

hook_theme() in module file:

```
function mycustom_theme() {
  return [
    'my_custom_slider_table' => [
    //'variables' => [
    //'header' => $header,
    //'rows' => $example_rows,
    //'attributes' => array('id' => $table_id),
    //],
    'variables' => [
    'slider ' => [],
    ],
  ],
];

}
```

my-custom-slider-table.html.twig file:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ 'Taxonomy select' }}</th>
      <th>{{ 'Reference Node' }}</th>
      <th>{{ 'Options' }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr> <td>{{ slider }}</td><td>Test Sponsors</td><td>Edit/Delete</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to get the output of $custom_categories variable in twig file, for the first td in {{ slider }} . Can you please help, new to Drupal8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to your `$build` render object. Here's a piece of sample code, in this case from a Block plugin with a form on it, similar to yours:

```
...
in my BlockPlugin
..



public function build() {
    // getConfiguration returns the values from the form I have and save to a config object.
    $source = $this->getConfiguration()['source'];
    $access_token = $this->getConfiguration()['access_token'];

    $build = [
      '#theme' => 'my_fancy_search_widget',
      '#source_data' => $source,
      '#access_token' => $access_token,
    ];
    return $build;
  }


...
in my .module file:
...


/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
  'my_fancy_search_widget' => [
      'template' => 'main-search',
      'variables' => [
        'source_data' => NULL,
        'access_token' => NULL,
      ],
  ];
}
```

in my twig template I can print these vars with `{{ source_data }}` and `{{ access_token }}`